# Can the F5 key be disabled in a navigation window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, key, navigationwindow, pagefunction

I have a small application that uses a navigation window and a set of pages. My application is not a browser per se and thus I dont want the user to be able to refresh the page by pressing F5. Is there a way to disable this key in my application? Many thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could disable refreshing altogether, by attaching a handler to the `Navigating` event:

```
yourNavigationWindow.Navigating += OnNavigating;

// ...

void OnNavigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Refresh)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Both solutions are good. I'll go for Jens though. Thanks to both. This works now! Edgar

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the CommandBinding from the NavigationWindow.
NavigationCommand.Refresh

Something like:

```
CommandBinding removeBinding=null;
foreach(CommandBinding cb in navigationWindow.CommandBindings){
 if(cb.Command==NavigationCommand.Refresh){
   removeBinding=cb;
   break;
 }
 if(removeBinding != null){
   navigationWindow.CommandBindings.Remove(removeBinding);
 }

}
```